# Taking cartesian product of two huge files using hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, out-of-memory, cartesian-product

We have two files `file1` and `file2` which have a huge number of lines, lets say a billion lines each. The goal here is to take a cartesian product of the files.

So if `file1` has `m` lines and `file2` has `n` lines the cartesian product output would have `m*n` lines.

I could think below solution for this problem:

1. Write `mapper1` which reads each line as `<line_number, line_content>` from `file1` and outputs `<const, file1_marker+line_number+line_content>`.
2. Write `mapper2` which reads each line as `<line_number, line_content>` from `file2` and outputs `<const, file2_marker+line_number+line_content>`.
3. Write `mapper3` which reads from both the output files and outputs `<const, list_of_file1_and_file2_line_contents>`.
4. Write a reducer which gets the `mapper3` output and while traversing the values combines every `file1_marker+line_number` value with every `file2_marker+line_number` value it sees (It could be made faster by hashing etc.) and outputs `<file1_line_content, file2_line_contents>`.

But it appears that the amount of memory will be an issue here. So I am looking for a more memory efficient solution if possible.

Please suggest.

Comment: If each file has a billion lines, then I think memory is the least of your problems. The Cartesian product would have a quintillion (= one billion billion) lines. If your computer could handle one million lines per second, it would still take about 30,000 years to compute, and several exabytes (= 1,000,000,000 GB) of storage. (Even with a million lines per file, it would still take ~11 days and many terabytes of storage.)

Comment: Sure. There would be hardware constraints in terms of CPU, memory, storage and network. But the question was asked in an interview so I am just trying to get the best answer. A company getting into a real situation like this would probably be doomed for ages. :D